# NCBI EUtils. Get Homolog infromation using Gene ID

Tags: bioinformatics, homology

How to retrieve homologs information in xml or json format from NCBI using gene ID?

I tried one URL:

```
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=homologene&geneid=9&WebEnv=???&query_key=???
```

I dont know what to add in question mark regions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure programming question better suited for BioStars.

Comment: I think the default format is xml. See more about EUtils [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Entrez Programming Utilities Help [Internet]](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/):

> Input: Any Entrez text query (&term); Entrez database (&db);
>   &usehistory=y; Existing web environment (&WebEnv) from a prior
>   E-utility call

To avoid the error messages, web1, and key1 can be used as terms (these are usually being used to associate with other searches), however this returns no data, probably because the ID you supplied was simply "9", and it remains unclear exactly what you're searching for in the context of other queries.

For example:

```
esearch.fcgi?db=<database>&term=<query>&usehistory=y

# esearch produces WebEnv value ($web1) and QueryKey value ($key1)

esummary.fcgi?db=<database>&query_key=$key1&WebEnv=$web1
```

So whilst `view-source:eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=homologene&geneid=9&WebEnv=web1&query_key=key1` is a valid query, it's not pointing to anything.